# Unmap of NumPy memmap

Tags: python, numpy, mmap

I can't find any documentation on how numpy handles **unmapping** of previously memory mapped regions: `munmap` for `numpy.memmap()` and `numpy.load(mmap_mode)`.

My guess is it's done only at garbage collection time, is that correct?

Comment: It would be an excellent tool if NumPy supported some manually-controlled notion of `munmap`. For example, I could load some array `x` with some `mmap` mode turned on. At some point I read `x[0:100]`, and then later I read `x[101:200]`. I want to be able to call `numpy.munmap(x[0:100])`, and have the result be such that only the elements of `x[101:200]` are loaded in memory, and any references to `x[0:100]` would have to re-`mmap` them when evaluated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's only closed when the object is garbage-collected; `memmap.close` method does nothing.

You can call `x._mmap.close()`, but keep in mind that any further access to the `x` object will crash python.